# macOS Python3.7.4 won't import wx and pip won't install it

Tags: python-3.x, macos, wxpython

Trying to run `wxPython` on **MacBook** Air with `macOS 10.14.6.`  Couple of issues.

When I ran in `3.7.1 (installed while using Anaconda)` and run a `wx script`, I get this error:

> This program needs access to the screen. Please run with a
>   Framework build of python, and only when you are logged in
>   on the main display of your Mac.

I installed `3.7.4 framework` but when I try to run `import` or `pip` I get the following report:

```
Grahams-MacBook-Air:~ grahamhansen$ python3.7
Python 3.7.4 (v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 14:54:52) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wx'
>>> brew install wxpython
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    brew install wxpython
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I installed `3.7.4 at the OS level`.  I am stuck..

Comment: You need to run `brew install wxpython` **outside** of Python in Terminal.

Comment: Thanks. I did as you suggested then tried to import wx.  Got the following response:

Grahams-MacBook-Air:~ grahamhansen$ python3.7
Python 3.7.4 (v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 14:54:52) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wx'

Comment: I ran 'pip show wxPython' to see where it was installed 
Got the following
Grahams-MacBook-Air:~ grahamhansen$ pip show wxPython
Name: wxPython
Version: 4.0.6
Summary: Cross platform GUI toolkit for Python, "Phoenix" version
Home-page: http://wxPython.org/
Author: Robin Dunn
Author-email: robin@alldunn.com
License: wxWindows Library License (https://opensource.org/licenses/wxwindows.php)
Location: /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: pillow, six, numpy
Required-by:

Comment: Problem resolved.  Adjusted the path to look for Python 3.7 first.